# Scalable buttons for responsive layout?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to create a UI with 4 buttons in every corner of the screen. 
The size of the buttons should be responsive, from the respective corner to the middle. 
If the resolution changes, the size of the buttons should also adjust so that they 
always extend from the corner to the middle, divided in four pieces of equal size.

That the buttons behave repetitively and stay in the corner works,
only the size of the buttons, that does not work.

I was not able to solve my problem via the Inspector, is there a way?
Is that only possible if I use images instead of buttons?

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Comment: All controls have 4 properties 1) Left 2) Top 3) Width 4) Height.  So when the layout changes the width of the buttons should be the  layout width /2 and the height of the buttons should be layout height / 2.

Comment: Thank you. But the question was for a non-code-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches, you could use layouts but this is quite simple so you can do it with inspector.

You can set the anchors:

- Top left xmin = 0, xmax = 0.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1
- Top right xmin = 0.5, xmax = 1, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1
- Bottom left xmin = 0, xmax = 0.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.5
- Bottom right xmin = 0.5, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.5

Set set all the left, right, top and bottom values to 0.

Now the anchors are based on screen position (middle (0.5) or edges (0 and 1)) so it will reset with screen sises. The corners of each box is set to 0 distance so they will stick with their anchors.

Comment: It is exactly as I wanted it to be. Thanks alot.